# Getting undefined reference error at adding simple class to library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am working with a rather sizeable library which uses CMake for compilation/linking. I need to add some functionality, thus I need to add some classes to the library. The problem is that when I add even a simple helloWorld class to the library, and try to call it from some main function, I get undefined reference problem at link time. When I looked into the built code ("CMakeFiles" within the library folder), my class hasn't been compiled by CMake (and thus, for instance, there is no HelloWorld.o file in there).

Can somebody point out where I am going wrong? Do I need to explicitely tell CMake to compile this class? (if yes, how?). I am novice in CMake, so don't know how to tackle this problem.

I call the function like this.
``

```
GSROrdinary sord;
```

The error message, I get, is something like this.

```
undefined reference to beep::GSROrdinary::GSROrdinary()
undefined reference to beep::GSROrdinary::~GSROrdinary()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to tell CMake to compile your class. I suggest that you check out some CMake tutorials that can be found online. Here is a nice one: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php - pay particular attention to the CMakeLists.txt file and syntax. You will have to modify your lib's CMakeLists.txt in order to add a new class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly add your new file to the CMake file so that they get compiled and linked.

This [commented sample](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html) could give you a start (basically you have to look for a `add_library (LIBNAME files)` directive in one of your CMakeLists.txt files and add your new file there, but you should also possibly read the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html).